# Cannot Call "NotInheritable" Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scope

in my asp.net/vb.net web application project i've some NotInheritable class.

I've this class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class GestioneConstants

    Public Shared FIRST_CONST As String                = "firstConst"
    Public Shared SECOND_CONST As String               = "firstConst"


End Class
```

And with this all works good.
Now i've a second class

```
Public NotInheritable Class Utilities

   Public Shared Function firstFunction() As String

      return "firstFunction"

   End Function

End Class
```

These 2 classes are in the same folder

Now, i've this cases:

1. If i try to use GestioneConstants from Utilities it works
2. If i try to use Utilities from GestioneConstants don't works
3. If i try to use GestioneConstants and Utilities from another
   NotInheritable class works with GestioneConstants but not with
   Utilities
4. If i try to use GestioneConstants and Utilities from an asp page or
   an handler works with both.

How can i've this behaviour??

I've tryed to add "imports myAppNamespace" but i still can't see "Utilities"

If i try to digit: imports.  i can see GestioneConstants as autocomplete, but can't see Utilites.

Comment: We are not psychic, please tell us what the error is.  Saying it "don't work" doesn't help at all.  What namespace is your Utilities class in?